# Javascript recursion not traversing back up the chain

Tags: javascript, html, xml, recursion

I am trying to create an HTML page that will allow me to output all the node names of the elements in the XML file in more or less the same way that you would read them, e.g.:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c></c>
 </b>
 <d>
  <e></e>
 </d>
</a>
```

would output:

```
a
 b
  c
 d
  e
```

I am using a Javascript function to recursively traverse through the XML document to achieve this. However, the function I have created only traverses to the lowest level once and then stops, producing, e.g.:

```
a
 b
  c
```

This is my Javascript function

```javascript
function printChildren(node){
 if(node.childNodes.length > 1){
  y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(node.nodeName)[0].childNodes;
  for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){
   if(y[i].nodeName!="#text"){
    document.write("<br>--->" + y[i].nodeName);
    alert(y[i].nodeName);
    printChildren(y[i]);
   };
  };
 };
};
```

I am not sure if my approach is wrong, or if the function is just breaking after it finishes the first level of recursion. I am testing this in Mozilla Firefox in case it is due to some quirk of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the children the way that you think you are.

```
if(node.childNodes.length > 1){
```

Here, you're only visiting nodes that have more than one child, but it seems like you'd want to visit the single children of a node, too, wouldn't you?  Then, when you actually retrieve children with

```
  y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(node.nodeName)[0].childNodes;
```

consider what happens if there are multiple elements with the same name as `node`; every time you visit one of them, you'll iterate through the children of the first node with that name.  In your example, this doesn't happen, but if you had

```xml
<a>
  <b><c1></c1></b>
  <b><c2></c2></b>
</a>
```

then when you try to visit the second `b` element, you'll retrieve the children of the first `b` element.  Why not just `node.childNodes`?  Then you could just do:

```
y=node.childNodes;
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){
```

without any checking of how many children `node` has;  if it has zero, then `childNodes` is a sequence of length zero, you still iterate over them correctly.

Comment: Wow, I am a bonehead for not seeing that, that explains the weird behavior I have been experiencing. So I guess I would have to split that line into two essentially, get the tags by name in one variable, then iterate over the result and grab the individual children?

Comment: Nvm, you are absolutley right, node.childNodes make way more sense, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do what you are trying to accomplish, make sure you are grabbing the nodes properly.  I used all HTML to demonstrate (JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6WNdZ/ -- the fiddle seems to only show up after you hit run):

```
<hmtl>
    <head>
        <script>
            function printChildren(node, depth) {
                if (!depth) { depth = 1; }
                for(var x = 0; x < node.childNodes.length; ++x) {
                    if (node.childNodes[x].nodeName == '#text') { continue; }
                    var space = '';
                    for(var y = 0; y < depth; ++y) {
                        space += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
                    document.write(space + node.childNodes[x].nodeName + "<br />");
                    printChildren(node.childNodes[x], depth + 1);
                }
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                var root = document.getElementById('container');
                printChildren(root);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <a>
                <b>
                    <c></c>
                </b>
                <d>
                    <e></e> 
                </d>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very clear example, I appreciate the time you took to give such a complete answer. I accepted @Joshua Taylor's answer because it addressed the exact issue a little more clearly however. Thanks though, very helpful still!